# how to fix this query of sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

[Address Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcskE.png)[UserTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJy3H.png)This Query is working perfectly fine in SQL Server Management Studio.
But when I am trying to run this query in C# it gives an exception please help me.

I Have tried many things but unable to resolve this problem.

SQL QUERY

```
set @LATITUDE=12 
set @LONGITUDE=12
Select * FROM [ChefODine].[dbo].[User] Inner Join [ChefODine].[dbo].[Address] on [ChefODine].[dbo].[User].AID=Address.ID
WHERE AID IN (
SELECT Top 5 ID
FROM [ChefODine].[dbo].[Address]
ORDER BY (ABS(ABS(LAT)-ABS(@LATITUDE)))+ABS(ABS(Lng)-ABS(@LONGITUDE)))
```

C# CODE

```
public HttpResponseMessage getNearByChef(double lat, double lng)
{
    var user = db.Users.SqlQuery("Select * FROM [ChefODine].[dbo].[User] Inner Join [ChefODine].[dbo].[Address] on [ChefODine].[dbo].[User].AID=Address.ID WHERE AID IN( SELECT Top 5 ID FROM[ChefODine].[dbo].[Address] ORDER BY(ABS(ABS(LAT) - ABS("+lat+"))) + ABS(ABS(Lng) - ABS("+lng+"))) ");
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,user);
}
```

Here is the Exception:

> "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>   "ExceptionMessage": "The 'ObjectContent'1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
>   "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
>   "StackTrace": null,
>   "InnerException": {
>       "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>       "ExceptionMessage": "The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'ChefODineModel.User'. A member of the type, 'Date_time', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.",
>       "ExceptionType": "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException",
>       "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.GetMemberOrdinalFromReader(DbDataReader storeDataReader, EdmMember member, EdmType currentType, Dictionary'2 renameList)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.GetColumnMapsForType(DbDataReader storeDataReader, EdmType edmType, Dictionary'2 renameList)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.CreateColumnMapFromReaderAndType(DbDataReader storeDataReader, EdmType edmType, EntitySet entitySet, Dictionary'2 renameList)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.InternalTranslate[TElement](DbDataReader reader, String entitySetName, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, EntitySet& entitySet, TypeUsage& edmType)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternal[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass65'1.b__64()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func'1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass65'1.b__63()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func'1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryReliably[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet'1.<>c__DisplayClass11.b__10()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator'1.MoveNext()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.d__1b.MoveNext()"

Comment: Provide an exception so we can help you with it.

Comment: @ArturMichajluk done

Comment: First off, wow on the Apil fools effects.  I vote to make them the new standard.  But to your question.. fist ff, use StringBuilder or the "$' operator... but what error are you getting?

Comment: Can you also provide sample output from the query? What is value on `user`? It says that JSON formatter can't handle formatting data from user to json.

Comment: You have to provide the datetime field in a form of string. Other option is to transform to epoch date format

Comment: Show your table schemas and data please

Answer (score 0):

> "The data reader is incompatible with the specified
>   'ChefODineModel.User'. A member of the type, 'Date_time', does not
>   have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.",

The user object cannot be mapped with ChefODineModel.User because date_time doesn't exist in the Dto Model.
beside that you can use SqlParameter when you have to pass data into the query

```
public HttpResponseMessage getNearByChef(double lat, double lng)
        {
            string query = @"Select u.* FROM [ChefODine].[dbo].[User] u
                             Inner Join [ChefODine].[dbo].[Address] on [ChefODine].[dbo].[User].AID=Address.ID 
                             WHERE AID IN( SELECT Top 5 ID FROM[ChefODine].[dbo].[Address] ORDER BY(ABS(ABS(LAT) - ABS(@LATITUDE))) + ABS(ABS(LATITUDE) - ABS(@LONGITUDE)))";
            var user = db.Users.SqlQuery(query, new SqlParameter("@LATITUDE", lat), new SqlParameter("@LONGITUDE", lng)).ToList();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, user);
        }
```

Comment: it gives an exception " The multi-part identifier "ChefODine.dbo.User.AID" could not be bound."

Comment: Can you post the class ChefODine.dbo.User? and ChefODineModel.User